# How the user control render works?

Tags: wpf

In `MainWindow.xaml` I have a userControl `<control:IBDataGrid></control:IBDataGrid>`;And I let the `IBDataGrid` to handle its own logic.

```
public IBDataGrid()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Ib = new IBQuoteSource();
    _vm = new WatchListViewModel(Ib);
    WatchList.DataContext = _vm;
    _vm.Subscribe();
}
```

Now the problem is The `MainWindow` begin to **Load** the `IBDataGrid` before I Debug or Start the program, But I want it to load the userControl when I click **Start Without Debugging**. [Right now The Stock Quote begin to update before running the program ].
Is there someway to work around this problem or do I need to redesign the Logic?
[image]

**Update1**
Using Mike's answer did stops update the Quotes before starting the program,but then the Quotes stop to update after start the program..

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
    Ib = new IBQuoteSource();
    _vm = new WatchListViewModel(Ib);
    WatchList.DataContext = _vm;
    _vm.Subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would probably be to disable subscriptions when running in the designer:

```
public IBDataGrid()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Ib = new IBQuoteSource();
    _vm = new WatchListViewModel(Ib);
    WatchList.DataContext = _vm;

    if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        _vm.Subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `if` statement, then step through to make sure the subscription executes when running in the debugger.  This should not change your behavior at all when running the app; it should only prevent certain code from running in the VS designer.  If your subscription doesn't function properly at runtime, then you probably have a separate issue.